# Scrolling through a list with an unknown type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a class that I call a method from a string Name with the following code where TalentProfile is my class I  running the method against and returning an unknown object type.

```
public Object RegulatorValue
public Type RegulatorType

BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

            List<MemberInfo> members = Common.AttributeHelpers.GetFieldAndPropertyList(this.TalentProfile, bindingFlags);

            foreach (MemberInfo member in members.Where(t => t.Name == methodName))
            {
                this.RegulatorValue = member.GetValue(this.TalentProfile);
                this.RegulatorType = this.RegulatorValue.GetType();
                this.Regulator = methodName;
            }
```

This works great if I bring back something like a string but I am having trouble when I bring back a list.  I have one method in particular that brings back a list. If I hard code a foreach to look for phonenumber it works great.  I would like to be able to go through the list without knowing what type the list is made up off and then go through the properties of the item in the list and be able to do something with that.

Comment: What "something" would you like to be able to do with the properties of the item in the list?

Answer (score 0):

The most basic type of collection in .net is IEnumerable. Cast your value to `IEnumerable` and iterate it.

```
IEnumerable enumerable = (IEnumerable)member.GetValue(this.TalentProfile);
if (enumerable != null)
{
    IEnumerator enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        object obj = enumerator.Current;
        // do something with obj
    }
}
```